# frame with transparent background in uwp app

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I created an uwp app. In my page I have two frame.
I put an image for the background of my page and what I want is to set transparency for the background of my frames in c# code but I don't know how to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the transparency of the Background of the frames.. by assigning names to them first .. say you have frame names - frame1 and frame2 ..
To change opacity of their background :

```
frame1.Background.Opacity = 0.5; // range of opacity is 0 to 1 (0 being fully transparent)
```

Hope this solves your problem ..! 
Also if you are showing other pages in your frame you need to set their grid background opacity too.